# AngularJS add jQuery dom eventlisteners after ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I am migrating a D3 based website with charts to angular. Each individual chart will still be drawn by D3, but each one will have it's on angular `directive` that manages the chart.

One of the chart elements consists of a chart (SVG) and a HTML table that acts as its legend.

```
[ svg (chart) ][ table (legend) ]
```

D3 draws the chart and I use `ng-repeat` to draw the legend. In this case both the legend and the chart needs to be interactive: need to have DOM eventlisteners. However the directive's controller is run *before* ng-repeat has drawn the legend (so the DOM elements do not exist yet).

view:

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg></svg>
    <div class="valign">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>BTC</th>
                <th>USD</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="legend item-{{item.title}}" title="{{item.title}}">
                <th>{{$index + 1}}</th>
                <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                <td>{{item.btc | bitcoin}}</td>
                <td>{{item.usd | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

directive:

```
angular
  .module('d3.charts', [])
  .directive('volumeElement', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // todo: this needs to be changed upstream in the volume controller
        scope.mode = '24h';

        // the d3 chart function
        var chart = new window.WZB.VolumeChart(
          element.find('svg')[0],
          scope.data
        );

        var $paths, $legend;

        var render = function() {
          chart.mode = scope.mode;
          chart.render();

          $paths = element.find('.interactive');

          addHovers();
        }

        var addHovers = function() { 
          // PROBLEM: at this point the ng-repeat has not populated the legend yet
          $legend = element.find('.legend')
          $paths.hover(function(e) {
            var $path = $(e.target);
            var title = $path.attr('title');

            var legend = $legend
              .filter(function() {
                var nonActive = $(this).attr('title') !== title;

                if(!nonActive)
                  $(this).removeClass('blur')

                return nonActive;
              })

              $paths
                .not($path)
                .add(legend)
                .addClass('blur');
            }, function() {
              $paths.add($legend)
                .removeClass('blur');
            })
        }

        render();
      },
      templateUrl: '/volume-element.html'
    }
  })
```

I am using jQuery for more advanced DOM manips, I can't only rely on angular's `ng-mouseover` directive because I need event listeners for both the angular generated table and the D3 generated SVG.

How can I execute code as soon as `ng-repeat` has populated the legend?

---

Hacky solution:

```
// todo: proper fix
// see @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035289/angularjs-add-jquery-dom-eventlisteners-after-ng-repeat
setTimeout(addHovers, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored the code, I wasn't thinking in the angular way. The new directive is contained  and d3 also creates the table, instead of mixing angular and d3 for the same visualization. This way I don't need jQuery anymore at all.